# Can a faulty Car self starter damage the battery?

Tags: battery, battery-drain

My almost 3 months old battery has gone bad and is giving voltage around 10V. Service centre tells me that my City's Self starter is the culprit as its putting too much load on the battery and is advising to replace it. Alternator is working fine.

Is there such a thing as the self putting too much load on battery?

Comment: The only scenario I can think of would be if the starting occurred frequently without letting the engine run for a significant amount of time afterwards.  Starting an engine is the biggest load that you car battery will probably ever see in a normal lifetime. Successive starts - with no recharging - will wear it down.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the battery is only three months old, it should still be under warranty and should be easily replaceable. Depending on the vehicle, it may be required to have a different *type* of battery. I've seen the self start cars needing a Air Gas Mat (AGM) battery over a typical lead acid battery. If you don't have the right one in there, this may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. @mike65535, that has not happened with my car, service centre says the starter has gone faulty, and is implicitly running for longer duration than required.

Comment: @pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I am pretty sure they have put the correct battery type in the vehicle as its the Honda authorised service centre.